# Demo code to process pdf files in springboot webservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have 2 springboot rest web services.. one is R1 and one is R2
Another code is calling R1 and passing a pdf file. R1 calls R2 internally . R2 processes pdf file, extracts the contents and is suppose to return the json object.
but the calls are not reaching to the controllers even though i am calling calling correct uri.

`

```
@RequestMapping("/")

  public class PDFDemoController { 
        @RequestMapping(path="/{processPDF}",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA+";charset=UTF-8",method=RequestMethod.POST)

    public pdfBeanDTO processPDF(@PathVariable("processPDF") String pathVar, @RequestParam("value") int varvalue,@RequestBody pdfSetter pdffileSetter, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {

String decodeValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(headers.getFirst("token")).toString();

        if(pathVar.equalsIgnoreCase("processPDF") && varvalue==1 && decodeValue.equalsIgnoreCase("granted")) {

            pdfBean = pdfProcess.processPdf(pdffileSetter);
            return pdfBean;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Encoded Oauth token is different");
        }
        return null;
    } `
```

R2:
`

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class pdfProcessController {
@RequestMapping(value="/readPdf",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<Object> setPDFAndCall() {
            HttpHeaders responseHeader = new HttpHeaders();
            String token = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("granted".getBytes());
            responseHeader.add("token", token);
            pdfBean = pdfServiceClass.pdfProcess(responseHeader);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(pdfBean,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

`

Any isssue with the controllers and need to changed?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format your code properly.

Comment: @Turing85 ... I have updated.